# HTML5 Input datetime-local Get Date Object Cross Browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html, datetime, cross-browser

I have an HTML5 webpage (using asp mvc3 and razor) which has a datetime-local input as below:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="StartTime" id="StartTime" data-val-required="The Event Start Time field is required." data-val="true">
```

If the browser supports a native datetime picker then I use it, else I use the jQueryUI date picker + a time picker plugin.

I have both server-side and client-side validation to check that this date is in range. The server-side validation works fine with parsing the datetime string and validating it, but I am having a problem with client-side validation for browsers which natively support the datetime picker.

```
var startdatevalue = $('#StartTime').val();
var value = $('#EndTime').val();
var dateStart, dateValue;
if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    //TODO: this doesn't seem to work in safari mobile
    dateStart = Date.parse(startdatevalue);
    dateValue = Date.parse(value);
}
else {
    dateStart = Date.parseString(startdatevalue.trim(), "@Constants.DateTimeFormat");
    dateValue = Date.parseString(value.trim(), "@Constants.DateTimeFormat");
}
```

As per the comment in the above code, this works in Opera 11 (desktop) but not in Safari on the iPad.
Opera is returning a Date in the format "2011-12-01T12:00" but Safari appears to be doing something else (seems to be "2012-01-01 00:00").

Is there a cross browser way to get an actual Date object from the native date picker input?

Comment: `Date.parseString` is not a standard method; you'll need to show us the code for that.

Comment: @Domenic, that is an extension method and works fine for the browsers which don't support the date picker. My problem is in the true branch of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is [`valueAsDate`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-valueasdate) not returning a Date object?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this attribute (doesn't seem to be mentioned much in examples). This works if I change the input type to 'datetime', but it returns null for 'datetime-local'. I really need local time presented to the user.